# Using patsubst to convert one path into another

Tags: c++, c, makefile, pattern-matching

In order to make the directory strcuture of my project a bit more organized I want to put sourcefiles for the same modules into seperate directory. All objectfiles should be put into `obj` directory. I don't really want to replicate the source tree in the obj directory as well, so I'm looking for a way to remove the directory part from a source file to make it into the obj path.

So this is the current version, which would require the obj directory to be of the same layout as the source directory.

```
OBJDIR:= obj
SRCDIR:= src

SRC := propertyfile/propertyfile.cpp otheritems/file.cpp otheritmes/subtree/bla.cpp
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRC))
```

To make it more clear: My sources reside in

```
src/propertyfile/*
src/otheritems/*
src/otheritmes/subtree/*
```

and so on.

The objfiles should all be in obj without the intermediate directories. With the above patsubst, it simply replaces the src part to obj making i.e. `src/propertyfile/propertyfile.cpp` into `obj/propertyfile/propertyfile.o` but what I would like to have is `obj/propertyfile.o`

A pointer to a good explanation on how these patterns work and what parameters it accepts would also be helpfull.

UPDATE:

So far I made a little progress by using the following line:

```
OBJ :=      $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o)))
```

However now the build rule doesn't work anymore because the names don't match, so I would need a pattern that works for the build rule as well.

Comment: You might want to be careful with this though. What if you have two source files in different directories but with the same name?

Comment: Yes, I know that this is a risk but I can avoid it, by taking care not use the same filenames. After all, it's easier to navigate when I know which files belong to a certain module. If the same name would be required, it might be a candidate for a common subclass anyway.

Comment: I now decided to go with the directory structure replicated in obj as well. To not have to do this manually I use "mkdir -p `dirname $@`" in the rule. this way I can simply delete all in obj without worry. I know that mkdir -p is not portable, so you may have to find a different solution for systems that don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be using [vpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search).

Another way, something like:

```
OBJ := ${SRC:%.cpp=${OBJDIR}/%.o}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the rule evaluates to obj/path/file.o instead of obj/file.o